# I don't understand this linear transformation problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am learning linear algebra from brilliant.org, and I don't understand what this problem is asking for or why the answer is $24$,can anyone help me?

[This is the problem and the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLEED.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to include both the actual problem (not a screenshot) and some information about what you tried and where you are stuck. Do you understand the definitions of the terms? Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The problem is asking how many 2x2 matrices you can form using 4 letters

Comment: @EthanBolker Ordinarily, I would agree wholeheartedly with you, but this seems to be a sort of simple didactic exercise to test understanding of the text. Sometimes students just get stuck and need a little insightful push (and Daniel has provided that in his very good answer). I agree that the "homework grind" problems definitely need effort to be shown before help is given. (Oh, and no quibble about the "screenshot" thing - yes, effort should be taken to present the problem properly).

Answer (score 1):

The standard basis for the vector space of cubic polynomials is given by the $4$ polynomials:
$$
\mathbf{p}_{1}=x^3,\quad\mathbf{p}_{2}=x^2,\quad\mathbf{p}_{3}=x,\quad\mathbf{p}_{4}=1
$$
The standard basis for the vector space of $2\times2$ matrices is given by the $4$ matrices:
$$
\mathbf {M}_{11}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\quad 
\mathbf {M}_{12}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\quad 
\mathbf {M}_{21}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\quad 
\mathbf {M}_{22}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now each of these vector spaces has dimension $4$. Thus we can map $\mathbf{p}_{1}$ to one of $\mathbf {M}_{11}$, $\mathbf {M}_{12}$, $\mathbf {M}_{21}$, $\mathbf {M}_{22}$, that is we initially have $4$ choices. Say we map it to $\mathbf {M}_{11}$, then we have to map $\mathbf{p}_{2}$ to one of the remaining matrices $\mathbf {M}_{12}$, $\mathbf {M}_{21}$, $\mathbf {M}_{22}$, that is we have $3$ choices. Going on like this we find we have $4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1=4!=24$ choices in total for mapping the basis polynomials to the basis matrices.

Answer (score 0):

You want to form a $2\times 2 $ matrix with four elements {a,b,c,d} without repeating any element.

For the first spot you have$ 4$ options.

After your first spot is filled then for your second spot you have only $3$ options.

For the third spot you have only two options left and finally for the last spot you only have one option.

That makes a total of $$4\times 3\times 2\times1=24 $$options.